# ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string inspite of using TO_TIMESTAMP

Tags: oracle, date, insert, ora-01830

My query(when fired by application) fails to execute with this error in spite of using the `TO_TIMESTAMP` function.

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE_NAME (
  UPDATED_DATE,
  CREATED_DATE,
  TEST_SUBJECT,
  THIRD_DATE
) VALUES (
  TO_TIMESTAMP('2018-05-31 14:45:32.000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSxFF'),
  TO_TIMESTAMP('2018-05-31 14:45:32.000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSxFF'),
  'test',
  TO_TIMESTAMP('2018-06-09 14:45:00.000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSxFF')
)
```

Here's the error message -

```
{FAILED after 2 ms}
java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
```

This error is thrown only on one environment, but works fine on other environments.

Manually executing the query works fine too.

The session timestamp format on all the environments is the same (updated by trigger upon login).

Comment: You should post tables DDLs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[TL;DR]** Use Timestamp literals to avoid this whole issue:

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE_NAME (
  UPDATED_DATE,
  CREATED_DATE,
  TEST_SUBJECT,
  THIRD_DATE
) VALUES (
  TIMESTAMP '2018-05-31 14:45:32.000',
  TIMESTAMP '2018-05-31 14:45:32.000',
  'test',
  TIMESTAMP '2018-06-09 14:45:00.000'
);
```

If you cannot then check the `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` database/session parameter. If a decimal point is not `.` then the `x` format model will not match a `.` but will match whatever character the database/session is using and the string will not be matched.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a2814e/5)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE_NAME (
  UPDATED_DATE TIMESTAMP,
  CREATED_DATE TIMESTAMP,
  TEST_SUBJECT VARCHAR2(20),
  THIRD_DATE   TIMESTAMP
);
```

**Query 1**:

```
-- Set decimal separator to "." and thousands separator to ","
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '.,'    

INSERT INTO MY_TABLE_NAME (
  UPDATED_DATE,
  CREATED_DATE,
  TEST_SUBJECT,
  THIRD_DATE
) VALUES (
  TO_TIMESTAMP('2018-05-31 14:45:32.000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSxFF'),
  TO_TIMESTAMP('2018-05-31 14:45:32.000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSxFF'),
  'test',
  TO_TIMESTAMP('2018-06-09 14:45:00.000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSxFF')
)

SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE_NAME
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a2814e/5/2)**:

```
|          UPDATED_DATE |          CREATED_DATE | TEST_SUBJECT |            THIRD_DATE |
|-----------------------|-----------------------|--------------|-----------------------|
| 2018-05-31 14:45:32.0 | 2018-05-31 14:45:32.0 |         test | 2018-06-09 14:45:00.0 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
-- Set decimal separator to "," and thousands separator to " "
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ', '

INSERT INTO MY_TABLE_NAME (
  UPDATED_DATE,
  CREATED_DATE,
  TEST_SUBJECT,
  THIRD_DATE
) VALUES (
  TO_TIMESTAMP('2018-05-31 14:45:32.000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSxFF'),
  TO_TIMESTAMP('2018-05-31 14:45:32.000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSxFF'),
  'test',
  TO_TIMESTAMP('2018-06-09 14:45:00.000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSxFF')
)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a2814e/5/4)**:

```
ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
```

Another solution is to use `'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'` as the format model rather than relying on the `x` format model to always be consistent across instances/sessions.

Comment: Thanks @MT0 
it looks a promising solution.

I don't have control over query generation part, but i can certainly try to push `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '.,'` to the DB on this env. and see if that fixes it.

Thanks a lot for sharing the knowledge, really appreciate it.

Comment: @CaptainJackSparrow Just be aware that changing the session parameters can break other queries if they were relying on the default for those parameters. The best solution is to use something independent of those parameters if you can.

Comment: Hey @MT0 I've a follow up on this.
So I checked the DB parameters and value for `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` is already `.,` It's only when the application accesses the DB, that session has this parameter's value as `,`
Is there a different setting on database that needs to be altered for the application user's session parameter to have the correct value (`.,`)